# Get Courses depending on another relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a two relations called `Course` and `School`.

`Course` also has a datetime field `open_date`.

I want to return all course where the school tier is not 1, and whithin a certain date.

I want some rails code like this:

```
Course.includes(:school).where("school.tier <> ? AND open_date between ? and ?",1 , date1, date2)
```

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than "I want some Rails code".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
Course.joins(:schools).where("schools.tier <> ? AND schools.open_date between ? and ?",1 , date1, date2)
```

The `joins` clause will eliminate the Courses without School associated.

(if doesn't work, try with `joins(:school)`)

Comment: it's the 's' in schools.tier that was missing.